# SPI communication problem between Raspberry Pi and STM32

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi, c, spi, python

I've spent a couple of days to find answer to my problem. Currently I'm working on a project where an STM32L432KC microcontroller board and a Raspberry Pi 3B need to communicate over SPI. The OS on the PI is Rasbian stretch, the microcontroller code is bare metal.

The microcontroller's code is the following:

```
#include <stm32l432xx.h>
#include "spi.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "systick.h"
#include "clocks.h"


uint8_t rx_byte = 0x3;
uint8_t tx_byte = 0x5;

int main(void)
{
    init_PLL(20, 2, 0, HSI16); //set the system clock to 80MHz
    uart_init(); //for serial monitoring
    spi1_slave_init();


    while(1)
    {
        // send a byte
        if(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)
        {
            //printf("%x\n\r", tx_byte);
            SPI1->DR = tx_byte++;
        }

        //receive a byte
        if(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE)
        {
            rx_byte = SPI1->DR;
            //printf("%x\n\r", rx_byte);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to share the SPI initialization code, here it is:

```
#include "spi.h"

void spi1_slave_init(void)
{
    /***** clock configuration ******/

    //enable clock for port B
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOBEN;

    //enable clock for port A
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;

    // enable clock to the peripheral
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;

    /*****pin configuration********/

    /*set alternate function mode*/
    //MISO: PA_11
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(0b11 << (2 * 11));
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0b10 << (2 * 11));

    //MOSI: PA_12
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(0b11 << (2 * 12));
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0b10 << (2 * 12));

    //SCKL: PA_5
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(0b11 << (2 * 5));
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0b10 << (2 * 5));

    //SSEL: PB_0
    GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0b11);
    GPIOB->MODER |= 0b10;

    /*set the output speed to very high*/
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= ~((0b11 << (2 * 11)) | (0b11 << (2 * 12)) | (0b11 << (2 * 5)));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= ((0b11 << (2 * 11)) | (0b11 << (2 * 12)) | (0b11 << (2 * 5)));
    GPIOB->OSPEEDR &= ~(0b11);
    GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= 0b11;

    /* set alternate function 5 */
    GPIOA->AFR[1] &= ~((0xF << (4 * 3)) | (0xF << (4 * 4)));
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= ((0x5 <<(4 * 3)) | (0x5 << (4 * 4)));
    GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~(0xF << (4 * 5));
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (0x5 << (4 * 5));
    GPIOB->AFR[0] &= ~(0xF);
    GPIOB->AFR[0] |= 0x5;

    /*****SPI1 configuration********/

    // disable SPI1
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_SPE);

    // set CPHA and CPOL to zero
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_CPHA | SPI_CR1_CPOL);

    // disable software slave management
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_SSM);

    // recive and send message with MSB first configuration
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_LSBFIRST);

    // configure the MCU as slave device
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_MSTR);

    // select 8bit datasize
    SPI1->CR2 |= (0x7 << SPI_CR2_DS_Pos);

    // set RXNE (recive buffer is not empty) event's threshold to 8 bit
    SPI1->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_FRXTH;

    // TX DMA request enable
    SPI1->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_TXDMAEN;

    // enable the peripherial
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
}
```

the python code which runs on the PI is the following:

```
import spidev
import struct
from time import sleep

#setup SPI
spi_bus = 0
spi_device = 0
spi_max_rate_hz = 100000

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(spi_bus, spi_device)
spi.max_speed_hz = spi_max_rate_hz
#spi.bits_per_word = 8
spi.mode = 0b00

byte2send = 0xA

recv_byte = spi.xfer2([byte2send], spi_max_rate_hz, 200)
#recv_byte = spi.xfer2([byte2send])
print(hex(recv_byte[0]))
```

And now the problem: the received bytes on the PI side are not what I would expect after I ran the code repeatedly:
[image]

Why this sequence is not  0x5, 0x6, 0x7...? Is this a correct behaviour of the SPI communication? I even don't know where is the problem, the PI side with SPIdev or my code on the STM32 side? Is there any way that I could achieve a syncronous communication without these 0x0 bytes between the correct ones?

I really appriciate your help!

Comment: SPI is not like uart. The master controls the transfer. When the master sends a byte, it is receiving a byte from the slave at the same time. This means the first slave byte has to be preloaded into the spi peripheral. When the slave gets the first byte from the master, it has to load the next byte to send back before the master starts sending it’s next byte. So the slave side can be a bit tricky as there is no handshake.

Comment: @Kartman I thought the same, but then `if(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)` probably evaluates to true out of reset, so that value in the DR register will be pre-loaded, assuming the MCU gets there first, before the PC master sends something. Isn't the problem rather that SPI1->DR is 16 bits or such? That's what I would bet on.

Comment: I bet there's a setting 8 vs 16 bit SPI data. I don't remember all the details but not all STM32 are the same here I think. Please post the highly relevant `spi1_slave_init()` code.

Comment: I just RTFM, in SPI1_CR2 there's a DS field. What does it say? You need 0111 there for 8 bit (default setting).

Comment: Never use magic numbers, I will not read this kind of code

Comment: `SPI1->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_TXDMAEN;` you do not use DMA

Comment: Regarding the magic numbers, please see [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: Also you should only write to each register once. Long chains of write after write to the same register is nonsense and also dangerous, in case you happen to set something by accident. For example the `|=` does not set bits, it OR bits with the default reset values in the register.

Answer (score 1):

Your micro has TX & RX FIFOs and you need to force the correct access size to place the data (ot read the data from) to the FIFO.

```
*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = tx_byte++
```

same reading

```
tr_byte = *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;
```

You need init code to:

1. Initialize GPIOs as Alternate to the proper mode.
2. Start the SPI clock
3. Set the FIFO threshold
4. Set the SPI mode + data length.

Best show us your SPI init code.

Comment: This won't matter in case the DR is set to 16 bits which I suspect. You'll then get data according to the MSB/LSB setting, big or little endian.

Comment: @Lundin it makes a lot of difference.  1. Default RPI spidev  && STM32 SPI word length is 8 bits. 2. Using 32 bits access will place 32 bits to the FIFO.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the missing SPI initialization code, I added to my question.